# How do you use a storyboard reference in a Tab Bar Controller with Visual Studio?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a view controller in one storyboard that I'd like to reuse in another storyboard's Tab Bar Controller. In XCode, I can add a storyboard reference and then ctrl-drag from the Tab Bar Controller to it, and it shows up as another tab, just like a View Controller would in the same storyboard. I'm trying to do this in VS 2017 though and it doesn't seem to work. Or if it does, I'm unsure of how to do it. I tried adding a storyboard reference and ctrl-dragging, just like I do for normal View Controllers. I select "Tab" under "View Relationship" which pops up when I finish dragging, but it never makes the link and never makes the tab.

Is this even something that is valid? And if it is, is it a bug/limitation with VS that I can't do this, and is there a workaround?

**Edit:**

I managed to get this to work programmatically. Here's what I did in case anyone wants to know. However, I still would like to know the answer to my previous questions.

First, in your desired VC (I'm going to call it TestVC), make sure you add a **Tab Bar Item** (not a tab bar). Set up the title and image as you would normally. Then, in your Tab Bar Controller's ViewDidLoad method, do something like this:

```
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("StoryboardNameTestVCIsIn", null);
        var vc = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("TestVC");

        var existing = new List<UIViewController>(ViewControllers);
        existing.Add(vc);
        ViewControllers = existing.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this even something that is valid? And if it is, is it a bug/limitation with VS that I can't do this, and is there a workaround?

It is not support to add Tab relationship by this way. As you mentioned above, you could only implement that programmatically. Maybe in the near future Xamarin will support it like in Xcode.

Click on the segue , and you can see all the actions you can do.

[image]